# undefined reference class method minimal example

Tags: c++, linker, include

ive been programming alot of java lately and trying to get back into cpp. Im working on small example and have some issues importing classes/headers or whilst linking.

I get a undefined reference using this code at **line 5: mc.getval()**. Hopefuly you can tell me where my import/linking is off. Thank you!

minmain.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "minheader.h"
int main() {
    Minclass mc;
    std::cout << mc.getval();
}
```

minheader.h

```
#ifndef MINCLASS_H
#define MINCLASS_H
class Minclass {
        public:
        int getval();
};
#endif
```

minclass.cc

```
class Minclass {
    int val = 5;
    public:
        int getval() {return val;}
};
```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CXX=g++
RM=rm -f
CPPFLAGS=-g -Wall -Werror -Wextra
LIBS=minheader.h
SRCS=minmain.cc minclass.cc
OBJS=$(subst .cc,.o,$(SRCS))

all: minmain

minmain: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o minmain $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
minmain.o: minmain.cc 
minclass.o: minclass.cc
  
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) minmain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minclass.cc should look like this

```
#include "minheader.h"

int MinClass::getval() {
    return val;
}
```

And minheader.h should have the complete class definition including the `val` member variable.

```
#ifndef MINHEADER_H
#define MINHEADER_H

class Minclass {
    int val = 5;
    public:
        int getval();
};

#endif
```

It's also normal to name the include guard after the header file you are protecting not after the class that is the contents of the header file.

Your version declared two different `MinClass` classes and so the linker was not able to resolve the missing method.